# Count number of live concurrent streams

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream of streams. I'd like to know to transform this into a live count of many inner streams are currently live, i.e. not completed or errored.

How would I implement CountLiveStreams?

```
var source = new Subject<IObservable<Unit>>();
IObservable<int> count = source.CountLiveStreams();
```

Thanks!

Comment: `IObservable` is most likely not the correct type you want here, since it is not an active stream and it has only the method `Subscribe()`. Please edit your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do.

Comment: @Progman, do you mean it's not a hot observable? That's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static IObservable<int> CountLiveStreams<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source) =>
    source
        .SelectMany(xs =>
            xs
                .Materialize()
                .Where(x => x.Kind != NotificationKind.OnNext)
                .Select(x => -1)
                .StartWith(1))
        .Scan((x, y) => x + y);
```

It uses the same strategy as Theodor's answer of producing `1` and `-1` and then using `.Scan` to create a running tally, but I think it's clearer with a call to `.Materialize()`.

Comment: Nice! I would use `LastAsync` instead of `Where`, being paranoid about receiving multiple `OnCompleted` notifications. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - You mean if the observables are not following the rules? And where would you use it? Don't forget that this has to work with empty observables.

Comment: Yeap, my concerns are about bad-behaving observables. My guess is that `Materialize` should probably sanitize its input, but I wouldn't feel confident without checking it. I just checked it and it actually does. Extraneous `OnCompleted` are ignored. I should trust RX more! :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - And there's always the `.Synchronize()` operator that sanitizes the stream too.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an implementation of the `CountLiveStreams` operator:

```
public static IObservable<int> CountLiveStreams<T>(
    this IObservable<IObservable<T>> streamOfStreams)
{
    return streamOfStreams
        .Select(x => x.IgnoreElements().Select(_ => 0).Catch(Observable.Empty<int>())
            .Prepend(1).Append(-1))
        .Merge()
        .Scan(0, (accumulator, delta) => accumulator + delta)
        .Prepend(0);
}
```

Each emitted stream is converted to an `IObservable<int>` that emits 2 values, the value 1 at the start and -1 at the end. Then all value-pairs generated from all streams are merged into a single `IObservable<int>`, and finally all these numbers are accumulated using the `Scan` operator.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  In the end I went with the other answer since there was less code :)

Comment: @James ha ha! I guess I should use single-letter identifiers more often then. :-) Btw be aware that the `Materialize` operator adds some overhead, since it creates a [`Notification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229462(v%3Dvs.103)) for each message, which is an object that needs to be allocated and finally garbage collected. If your are observing many high throughput streams, you should take this into consideration.